# A question regarding Semi-Direct Products and natural inclusion map

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My understanding is that the natural inclusion maps $l_G:G \rightarrow G \rtimes H $ and $l_H:H \rightarrow G \rtimes H $ , define embeddings $G \rightarrow G \times 1$ and $H \rightarrow H \times 1$, which only intersect at $(e_g, e_h)$.

Does this imply the groups $G$ and $H$ themselves only intersect at $\{e\}$? If so, how can I show this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Often one writes that some group $K$ is a semi-direct product $G \rtimes H$ for arbitrary groups $G, H$ to mean that $(K,\cdot)$ is isomorphic to some group $((G\times H), \star)$ satisfying a semi-direct product of $(G,e_h) \rtimes (e_g,H))$.

For example, for symmetric groups, we say $S_n = A_n \rtimes S_2$, but mean: there are subgroups $G,H$ of $S_n$ such that $G \cong A_n$ and $H \cong S_2$ and $S_n$ is a semi-direct product of $G$ and $H$.

But in that case, we know that $G \cap H = \{e_k\}$; and $A_n \cap S_2$ doesn't provide much additional information no matter how you define it...